# NServiceBus - Recommended Number of Worker Threads for Commercial License

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, nservicebus

We recently upgrade our NServiceBus from Community to Commercial and it is licensed for 2 cores. When I look at the examples and online, I only ever see configurations for the 1 worker thread.

What is the recommended number of worker threads per core when it comes to commercial NServiceBus? Or is there a number of worker threads given the amount of system memory/processor resources? Or is this something I need to tweak until I find the 'sweet spot'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since threads may be blocked on IO (like talking to a DB/webservice), you wouldn't want to limit them to the number of cores. There is no back-of-the-envelope calculation for figuring out what the number should be. Tweaking to find the 'sweet spot' is probably the best approach.

Comment: It would be nice to know what a ballpark upper limit is on an example machine (say 4 core @ 2.4Ghz).  How many cores are too many? 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256?  Any of these considered going to far?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about threads for a 4 cores machine (rather than cores). In that case, I'd say 64 is probably as high as you'd want to go, YMMV.